# Application.CFC variable not available

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

In application.cfc I am defining a variable which must be available throughout a session.

```
<cfcomponent>
 <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,4,0,0)>
    <cfset this.sessionManagement = true>
    <cfset this.setClientCookies  = true>
    <cfset this.sessionTimeout    = createTimeSpan(0,0,90,0)>
    <cfset this.setdomaincookies  = true>

    <cfset this.myVar = "Hello">
</cfcomponent>
```

I tried several approaches to get the myVar in .cfm but to no avail.

```
Approach 1: <cfoutput>#myVar#</cfoutput>
Approach 2: <cfoutput>#session.myVar#</cfoutput>
Approach 3: <cfoutput>#application.myVar#</cfoutput>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If a variable has to be a available throughout a session, perhaps a session variable would be more appropriate.  Or maybe you just didn't say what you meant.

Answer (score 10):

You're confusing the placement of `Application.cfc`'s `this`-scoped settings with your own `application`-scoped variables.

Take a look at Ben Nadel's [Application.cfc tutorial](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-coldfusion-application-cfc-tutorial-and-application-cfc-reference.htm).

You basically want to put `application.myVar` in `OnApplicationStart()`:

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,4,0,0)>
  <cfset this.sessionManagement = true>
  <cfset this.setClientCookies  = true>
  <cfset this.sessionTimeout    = createTimeSpan(0,0,90,0)>
  <cfset this.setdomaincookies  = true>

  <cffunction name="OnApplicationStart">
    <cfset application.myVar = "Hello">
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then you should be able to reference it in your application as `application.myVar`.

Comment: Just to add to Chris' point, you're missing an name.

<cfset this.name = "AUniqueNameHere" />

From what I recall, if you don't specify a name ColdFusion will continuously rebuild your application and I've seen missing variable errors being a side-effect of that.

Also note that the name needs to be unique to avoid conflicts with other applications.